# How to send an email to gmail using php and GMAIL SMTP?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I already tried different examples on GitHub and other resources but still getting an error when using phpmailer. I am currently using xamp localhost. I already tried using my google account to send an email using XAMP sendmail, but when I try to send using phpmailer. I am getting this message.

(SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.

Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host. Connection failed. stream_socket_enable_crypto(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages: error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify failed.)

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'src/Exception.php';
require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'src/SMTP.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      //Enable verbose debug output
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            //Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     //Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   //Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'myemail@gmail.com';                     //SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'mypassword';                               //SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';            //Enable implicit TLS encryption
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    //TCP port to connect to; use 587 if you have set `SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS`

//Recipients
    $mail->setFrom('myemail@gmail.com', 'Mailer');
    $mail->addAddress('myemail@gmail.com', 'Joe User');     //Add a recipient

//Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  //Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
    $mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
```

Comment: try setting mail driver "$mail->driver=sendmail "

Comment: Thanks, I tried to add it on the server setting but still having the same error.

Comment: Read [the docs on certificate verification failure](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting#certificate-verification-failure).